# file_get_contents adds an extra amp;

Tags: php, curl, geolocation, file-get-contents

Hello Im trying to geolocate some municipalities,
Using the api directly to my browser i take the xml as a result.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?language=el&components=administrative_area:ΔΗΜΟΣ ΑΓΙΟΥ ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΥ|country:GR
```

But when I'm trying to parse it with php:

```
$area="ΔΗΜΟΣ ΑΓΙΟΥ ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΥ";
$map_url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?language=el&components=administrative_area:'.$area.'|country:GR';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$map_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Proclamations Parser');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//$response_xml_data =    file_get_contents($map_url);
//$data=simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
//var_dump($data);
```

when im using file_get_contents i get :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?language=el&amp;components=administrative_area:ΔΗΜΟΣ AΓΙΟΥ ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΥ |country:GR):
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

i noticed that the url changed: `language=el&amp;` there is an extra `&amp` that it wasn't there before file_get_contents.
I tried curl way but i take as a result a null

I used `urlencode()` function and nothing changed.
Do i have anything wrong?
And where this "amp;" coming from?

Comment: Try replacing `$area` with `urlencode($area)` in `$map_url`.

Comment: Curl still not working, file_get_contents doesnt throw an error, but returns wrong data. returns the location of the Country and not the administrative_area

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not add `amp;` to the URL on my end (PHP 5.5). Try adding also `$map_url = htmlspecialchars_decode($map_url);` and see if it works.

Comment: Again it returns wrong results